# How to insert PHP script into a wordpress without using a plugin

Tags: wordpress

Using wordpress plugin, I can easily insert php script into the back-end of wp-admin. But, this time, **I don't want to use plugin**. Is there a way to do this? I already searched on google but haven't found any answer to this. Most of those sites uses plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is two way to do this.

If you want to use PHP code in your widget text editor then you can do that by adding below code in your `function.php` file.

```
function php_execute($html){
    if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){ ob_start(); eval("?".">".$html);
    $html=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
return $html;
}
add_filter('widget_text','php_execute',100);
```

Clear cache if you are using any cache plugin and then try to add PHP code to your widget area like:

```
 <?php echo 'Hello!!!' ?>
```

If you want to add PHP code in your page or post editor then the best way is to create custom shortcode in `function.php` file something like:

```
function list_pages_function( $atts ) {
    return wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order');
}
add_shortcode( 'output_pages', 'list_pages_function' );
```

then you can use `[output_pages]` as shortcode in your page or post editor. See the [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) API.

Hope you will find this helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: @smzvax, Just Add "php_execute"  function in your function.php then go to Appearance->Widget select Text widget and add <?php echo 'Hello!' ?> code inside. It's working fine in my side for the widget. Check and if you have installed any plugin for that then disable it first.

Comment: Ah okay.thanks., How about adding PHP into the PAGES of wordpress?

Comment: For that, I think a good way is to add your PHP code in function.php file with add_shortcode function and then use that custom shortcode in your PAGES to run function and PHP script. Please see this link for the tutorial: https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/how-to-create-your-own-wordpress-shortcodes/  or you can generate custom shortcode function using shortcode generator: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode and use that shortcode also.